No RDS entry/CALs in per-device mode
I have Windows Server 2022, RDS installed in Workgroup. I'm using a "per-device" licensing and got an "Enterprise Agreement" with 10 devices. The Windows Server 2022 host is the license server.
lsdiag.exe states everything is ok after configuration of CAL and number of licenses.
When I connect with Windows 10, it works, but:

I don't see any "Issued" client on server side
No temporary license
No entry in "Windows 2022 - Installed RDS Per device CAL"

No log too in "Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows > TerminalServices—Licensing > Operational"
Sounds like if I was connected just as "classic mode" (I mean without RDS).

How are you connecting?

I'm using mstsc.exe
